# WP terms IDs by taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

My question is next: it is possible that 2 different terms, from 2 different taxonomies, to have the same ID?

From my experience, it must not, but I want to be sure, because, I am developing a plugin which add to default post new taxonomies, and I am using next method of saving: when term is saved, I am creating a option like next:

```
"prefix_taxonomy">$term->term_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, they cannot. The ID assigned to any object in a specific table in the DB is unique. The ID represent the object's place in the DB. ID's cannot be set and is auto assigned according to the entry's place in the DB.

These ID's never change, except when an object is deleted from the db and later reassigned.

Example, if the last term has a ID of 10, the next term will be assigned ID 11. If term ID 11 is deleted, and a new term is added, it will be assigned ID 12, and not ID 11. Empty ID's does not get reused.

It is therefore also not recommended to hard-code any ID's and they **will** differ from site to site